War Surplus film 616
After cleaning out our parents homes, my husband and I came across some War Surplus film. I  would like to find a place to develop  them. Does anyone know of such a place?

This is location-dependent. Also note, in the related questions in my comment below, several of the locations have closed, or changed names. The difficulty keeping that information correct and up-to-date is precisely why this question was closed as short-lived as a result of changing markets.

Related: Where can I get 4x5″, 5x7″, or 8x10″ color sheet film (or other hard-to-find exotic film) processed?, Where is a really good place to get film developed by mail?

Just for the information of anyone interested... 616 film
